# django heroku build can't find config vars

Tags: django, heroku

I have a staging app which is deployed but have some disturbing logs when trying to import the config vars from heroku. Here is a sample:

```
-----> Exporting application config values
-----> Loading environment information
cat: /tmp/d20210317-55-vc7xqe//tmp/d20210317-55-vc7xqe/ALLOWED_HOSTS: No such file or directory
/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/9f6bae6fc2432740f5d76d23e8fbcb5e7b35afaa/bin/compile: line 11: export: `/tmp/d20210317-55-vc7xqe/ALLOWED_HOSTS=': not a valid identifier
cat: /tmp/d20210317-55-vc7xqe//tmp/d20210317-55-vc7xqe/COMPRESS_ENABLED: No such file or directory
```

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you share more information from where you're defining those configurations? Like a print or a copy of a file. Just don't forget to omit sensible information.

Comment: The environment variables are defined in the settings of heroku admin for each app. See for example: https://www.google.com/search?q=heroku+admin+config+vars&rlz=1C9BKJA_enCH942CH942&hl=en-GB&prmd=inv&sxsrf=ALeKk03OhpP5i7LZ_KsAvyHHdfCiVA-n-g:1616080389758&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3yLzMkLrvAhWLG-wKHZluDTIQ_AUoAXoECAcQAQ&biw=1194&bih=715&dpr=2#imgrc=hiRulVlg5WZVtM

Comment: Ok, I'm aware of that, but can you share your definition? Just share a print-screen or copy-paste them here, but, as always, don't forget to omit sensible informations.